# Array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display a table which fetches data from a server and displays all the information in it. The code is printing my table header and information of the first object from the fetched API.

Its giving me an error.

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop. Check the render method of `MyTable`"

```
import React from "react";

export default class MyTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log(props);
  }

  createTable = () => {
    let table = [];

    let tableHeader = (
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {this.props.columns.map(column => {
            return <th key={column.name}>{column.name}</th>;
          })}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    );

    let tableRows = [];
    for (
      let i = this.props.pgNo * this.props.maxItems;
      i < i + this.props.maxItems;
      i++
    ) {
      if (i > this.props.users.length) {
        break;
      } else {
        let row = (
          <tr>
            {this.props.columns.map(column => {
              return (
                <td key={column.key}>{this.props.users[i][column.key]}</td>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        );

        tableRows.push(row);
      }
      let tableBody = <tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>;
      return (
        <table>
          {table}
          {tableHeader}
          {tableBody}
        </table>
      );
    }
  };
  render() {
    return <div className="col-sm-10">{this.createTable()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: [ReactJS => Lists and Keys => Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you gave a key for both th and td but you

> forgot to write a key in tr for row variable

Answer (score 1):

When rendering an array of React elements, a key on each element is needed for React to know how to update  each element.

```
const list = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]

class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return list.map(item => {
      return (
        <div key={item}>{item}</div>
      )
    })
  }
}
```

You can read more about it [here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Comment: even after giving a key it doesent display all of my data.

Comment: it still displays only 1 object from the fetched json data

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that your `<tr>` elements don't have keys. Try giving them `i` as a key.

```
if (i > this.props.users.length) {
    break;
} else {
    let row = (
      <tr> <--- You should have a key prop here
```

Try using 
`<tr key={i}>`

Comment: Using index as key is not recommended, it can cause buggy behaviour where an item won't update because its key did not.